# How do I detect if my program runs in an Active Directory environment?

Tags: c#, active-directory

How do I detect if my program runs in an Active Directory environment?

I'm using C# and .Net 2.0

Answer (score 7):

Try getting Environment.UserDomainName and comparing it to Environment.MachineName.  If the two are the same then it's likely that the user does not have a domain.  If they are not the same then the user is logged into a domain which must have a directory server.

Answer (score 4):

This code will check if the Computer itself is a member of a domain

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;


bool isDomain = false;

try
{
    Domain.GetComputerDomain();
    isDomain = true;
}
catch (ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException)
{
}
```

However the computer can be in a domain, but the currently logged in user may be a local user account. If you want to check for this use the `Domain.GetCurrentDomain()` function

Comment: I get false when I'm logged with a local user, true when logged with a domain user...

Comment: What about an NT4 domain without an active directory?

Comment: This is good, but not foolproof: `ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException` also gets thrown if the domain controller cannot be contacted for some reason, even though the machine is a domain member.

Answer (score 2):

One way might be to query the LOGONSERVER environmental variable.  That'll give the server name of your AD controller... Which, as far as I know, will be blank (or match current workstation? Not sure) if it isn't currently logged into a domain.

Example Usage:

```
string ADServer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOGONSERVER");
```

Comment: it will be a machine name too if computer is not a part of any domain

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.path.aspx

> To bind to the current domain using LDAP, use the path "LDAP://RootDSE", then get the default naming context and rebind the entry.

So without a domain the binding to "LDAP://RootDSE" should either fail or return nothing. I didn't try it for myself.

```
use System.DirectoryServices; // add reference to system.directoryservices.dll

...

DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
String str = ent.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0];
DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + str);
```

This is definitely a cleaner way of checking for an Active Directory than relying on an environment variable (which the user could delete or add to spoof the program).

Comment: +1 This works, thank you. The only thing is, when the machine is not a domain member it waits for about 5 seconds before throwing a COMException. So it may be better to call `Domain.GetComputerDomain()` or `IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName` first, then if that succeeds, do this.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that works:

using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;

Works with a local user and a domain user.

Comment: Looks promising, but the remark in the doc is a little concerning: "If a local computer is registered in a domain and then changes to a workgroup, the DomainName property still returns the previous domain name not the Empty" [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.domainname.aspx]